# ES8 await call isn't waiting for me

Tags: node.js, promise, async-await

My problem is I'm trying to await on some promises, but my await call seems to return to the calling function right away.

In the code below (part of a controller function handling a POST), the "files coming out" log after my function call is executed prior to the promises being executed. My async function seemingly returns at the "await" call.

However the "await" still does wait for all the promises to execute, so the "I just finished waiting" log *does* have the magic var inserted into the `req.files` correctly.

```
const upload = multer({
  storage: multer.diskStorage ({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => { cb(null, config.DESTINATION) }
  })
}).array(config.FIELD_NAME);

exports.upload_image = function(req, res) {

  upload(req, res, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.end("error uploading file");
    } 
    // got file ok, do validation
    checkAreDicom2( req.files );
    console.log("files coming out: ", req.files);

    return res.end("OK");

  });
}

async function checkAreDicom2(inFiles) {

  let promises = inFiles.map(function (file) {
    return new Promise( function (resolve, reject) {
      fs.createReadStream(file.path,{start: 128, end: 131, autoClose: true})
      .on('error',reject)
      .on('data', (chunk) => file.magic = file.magic ? file.magic += chunk : chunk)
      .on('end', resolve);
    });
  });
  await Promise.all(promises);

  console.log("i just finished waiting: ", inFiles);
  return;

}
```

Comment: `inFiles` still contains the promises. You need to assign the return value of `await` expression to a new variable to get the array of file data

Comment: Also you're forgetting that `checkAreDicom2( req.files )` returns a promise as well. You need to chain it with `.then()` or `await` it similarly to how you used `await` inside of it.

Comment: `async` functions are returns promise. If you want to wait until the function finishes you need to use either `.then()` (as with regular promise) or `await` (if you call async function inside another `async` function)

Comment: thanks guys!  ...got it figured out with your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `await` is waiting for the `Promise.all`, and the log after it is correctly delayed. However it does of course not block the caller of function.

So the callback in `upload_image` does not wait for the asynchronous processing, it just receives the promise that `checkAreDicom2(…)` returns - and discards it, and immediately logs something. You would need to await the asynchronous result explicitly here again.

```
exports.upload_image = async function(req, res) {
  try {
    await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      upload(req, res, (err) => {
        if (err) reject(err);
        else resolve();
      });
    });
    // got file ok, do validation
    await checkAreDicom2( req.files );
//  ^^^^^
    console.log("files coming out: ", req.files);

    return res.end("OK");
  } catch(err) {
    return res.end("error uploading file");
  }
};
```